# show() on nth element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time asker. Trying to make a hangman game. When I get keyboard input and match it to a letter in the word, my alert pops.  But the execution of the jquery code to show the nth span element inside the .word class does not. Is this a scoping issue?  What am I missing?

Thanks

```
$(function(){
  words = ["elephant", "tiger", "dragon"];
  var keypress = '';
  var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  var wordLetters = rand.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < wordLetters.length; i++) {
    $('.word').append("<span>  " + rand[i] +"  </span>");
    $('.word span').hide();
  }
  $('body').keypress(function(e){
    keypress = (String.fromCharCode( e.which ));
    for (var j in rand) {
      if (rand.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        if (keypress === rand[j]) {
          //alert('This Alert Works!');
          //sadly this does not work
          $(".word span:nth-child(" + j + ")").show();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Performance wise, I would buffer all `.word` in array, and then called `array[j].show()`

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived
>   from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning
>   that the counting starts at 1. For other selector expressions such as
>   :eq() or :even jQuery follows JavaScript's "0-indexed" counting. Given
>   a single  containing two `<li>`s, `$( "li:nth-child(1)" )` selects the
>   first `<li>` while  `$( "li:eq(1)" )` selects the second.
>
> The `:nth-child(n)` pseudo-class is easily confused with `:eq(n)`, even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   With `:nth-child(n)`, all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class. With `:eq(n)` only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the `(n+1)th` one (n is 0-based) is selected.

REF: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Use:

```
$(".word span").eq(j).show();
//OR
$(".word span:eq(" + j + ")").show();
//One would expect that the following would work since nth- selectors start at 1, but it does not
$(".word span:nth-child(" + (j+1) + ")").show();
```

Instead of:

```
$(".word span:nth-child(" + j + ")").show();
```

```js
$(function(){
  words = ["elephant", "tiger", "dragon"];
  var keypress = '';
  var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  var wordLetters = rand.split('');
  console.log( rand, wordLetters );
  for (var i = 0; i < wordLetters.length; i++) {
    $('.word').append("<span>  " + rand[i] +"  </span>");
    $('.word span').hide();
  }
  $('body').keypress(function(e){
    keypress = (String.fromCharCode( e.which ));
    for (var j in rand) {
      if (rand.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        if (keypress === rand[j]) {
          //alert('This Alert Works!');
          //sadly this does not work
          $(".word span:eq(" + j + ")").show();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `++j`, making sure the selector `nth-child(0)` is not used:

```
 $(".word span:nth-child(" + ++j + ")").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

two possible issues:

- span:nth-child(n) selects a span if it is the nth child, not necessarily the nth span, so - not knowing your html - it's safer to use span:nth-of-type instead
- css starts counting with 1, js with 0